# Multiple instances of an app with flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I'm running a Python application which uses flask and apache. When a second person uses the app it waits till the first process ends making everything pretty slow. It's supossed to run with atleast 20 users simultaneosly. What should I do? (sorry for my bad eng)

Comment: Could you show your code here? It'll make it easier for people to see what might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Using the simple app.run() from within Flask creates a single synchronous server on a single thread capable of serving only one client at a time.

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

`threaded=True` will process each request in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

apache should take care of that for you.
see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/ for details on how to implement this for a flask app.